# How to serialize VSTS CI branch builds

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops

VSTS allows you to select which branches automatically trigger a CI build by specifying a branch pattern.

However, my unit tests are using a real database which causes a problem when more than one build triggers e.g. master and feature-123 as they will clash on the database tests.

Is there a way of specifying that only one such build should be run at at time; I don't want to go away from executing tests against a real database as there are significant differences between an in-memory database and SQL Azure.

Comment: *unit tests are using a real database*. Then they **are not unit tests**. Unit tests have no external dependencies. You are describing **integration tests**.

Comment: Accepted, they might be better described as _low-level integration tests_ as what I'm trying to prove is that the ORM mapping is correctly defined and that we can talk to the database server correctly, i.e. there's no point in writing true integration tests for the API if you haven't proven the persistence layer.

Answer (score 1):

VSTS already serialize builds which are triggered by the same CI build.

Even CI build can be triggered by multiple branches, but **for a certain time, only one build is running by default** (unless you use pipelines to run builds concurrently).

Such as if both `master` branch and `feature-123` branch are pushed to remote repo at the time time, the CI build definition will trriger two builds serially (not concurrently).

---

If you are using pipeline and need to run the triggered builds serially, you should **make sure only one agent is used** for the CI builds. You can use the way below:

In your CI build definition -> Options Tab -> add demands to specify which agent you want to use for the CI build.

Assume in default agent pool, there are three agents with the agent name: default1, default2 and default3.

If you need to specify default2 agent to run the CI build, then you can add the demands as below:

[image]

Now even multiple branches have been pushed at the same time, they will be triggered one by one since only one agent is available for the CI build.

Comment: It is the multiple branches that I was having issues with, a master and a feature build were triggered within a few seconds of each other. I have multiple pipelines as I can't see how to limit this and still have build/release happening in parallel.

Comment: What if you clone the build definition, so that one is used for trigger `master` branch, the other is used for trigger `feature-123` branch separately?

Comment: Haven't tried that and don't want to really since it then means I have to keep the build definitions in sync - also wouldn't address if multiple features branches were committed at the same time, What would be nice is explicit control like under the Release pipeline where you can specify a policy

Comment: So you can also add demands in build definition to make sure only one agent can run the CI builds. I added the detail steps in the end of my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go

Comment: @PaulHatcher Does your CI build serial the triggered builds now?

Comment: if you are planning to do the same via .yaml file use following phases:
```- phase: Build
#  queue: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
  queue:
    name: Hosted Ubuntu 1604
    demands:
      - agent.name -equals Hosted Ubuntu 1604 10

  steps:
    - task: <taskname>
      displayName: 'some display name'
      inputs:
        value: '<input variable based on type of task'
        variableName: '<input variable name>'```

Comment: did not work as expected when the pipeline had more than one phases even though I had specified same pool demand for all phases in pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a YAML pipeline, you can use a [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) in stead of a regular job.

With a deployment job you select a named Environment you want to deploy to.

You can configure the Environment in azure devops under Pipelines->Environments and you can choose to add an [Exclusive Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-172-update#exclusive-deployment-lock-policy).

Then only one run can use the environment at a time and this serializes your runs.

Unfortunately, if you have multiple runs waiting for the environment (because one run currently has it locked), when the environment becomes unlocked only the latest run will continue. All the others waiting for the lock will be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it via .yml or .yaml file you can do following

```
- phase: Build 
  queue: 
    name: <Agent pool name> 
    demands: 
    - agent.name -equals <agent name from agent pool> 
  steps: 
    - task: <taskname> 
      displayName: 'some display name' 
      inputs: 
        value: '<input variable based on type of task' 
        variableName: '<input variable name>'
```